# What is the translation of the song in 40-Year-Old Virgin?

Tags: dialogue, translation, the-40-year-old-virgin

I'm not googling any of this stuff, but if you've seen the movie [*The 40 Year Old Virgin*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405422/) you know what I'm referring to.

The woman with the blond hair that was almost a crew-cut, the boss at the tech store, tells Steve Carrell's character about a gardener named Javier who took her virginity.  She sings a song that Javier sang to her.  All I got was the last word, "Futbol", which is "Soccer".  Does anyone know the translation of the rest of the song?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [IMDb trivia section](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405422/trivia?item=tr0724742) for the movie:

> The "beautiful old Guatemalan love song" sung by Javier to Paula translates to:
>
> When I clean my room
>     I can't find anything
>     Where are you going in such a hurry
>     To the soccer game.
>
> [Jane Lynch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Lynch) has told several interviewers that these "lyrics" were really a practice dialogue that she remembered from a high school Spanish class.

The sites containing the lyrics I found ([1](http://foxylibrarians.blogspot.co.uk/2006/05/un-partido-de-futbol.html), [2](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/kevin-hench/if-kissing-jessica-stein-_b_46258.html)) say the original Spanish she's singing is:

> Cuando limpiado mi cuarto
> No encuentro nada
> Adonde va con tanta prisa?
> Al partido de fútbol

And [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Cuando%20limpiado%20mi%20cuarto%0ANo%20encuentro%20nada%0AAdonde%20va%20con%20tanta%20prisa%3F%0AAl%20partido%20de%20f%C3%BAtbol) basically agrees with its usual margin of error.